# AppEngine SDK 1.8.5 and Eclipse Juno not working

Tags: google-app-engine, eclipse-plugin

I've installed the Eclipse plug-in for both GWT and Appengine on 3 different machines, all with Juno (4.2).  In each case, I get the following error:

"The selected App Engine SDK is not valid: Failed to initialize App Engine SDK at (path)."

Reinstalling the SDK does not make any difference.  Here is more info. about the different configurations I've tried:

Ubuntu 12.0.4, Java 7, Eclipse 4.2
Mac OSX 10.8.5, Java 7, Eclipse 4.2-32 bit
Mac OSX 10.8.5, Java 7, Eclipse 4.2-64 bit
Mac OSX 10.6.8, Java 6, Eclipse 4.2-64 bit

Any suggestions for what may be going wrong and configs I could try?  Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

I was getting the error "Failed to initialize App Engine SDK at '..path'" in Eclipse 4.3(Kepler) with Google App Engine SDK 1.8.5 and Java SDK 1.7.0_01

When I updated the Java SDK to 1.7.0_41 (latest one) this error disappeared.

Great relief!!

Answer (score 3):

I can confirm that using win7/sun jdk1.6.0_45/eclipse 4.2/gae sdk 1.8.4 the error occurred when updating to 1.8.5+ and that updating the jre that eclipse runs in to sun 1.7.0_45 solved the issue.

I can now add gae SDKs above 1.8.4.

I'm not sure why we could'nt have an error modal in eclipse to that effect.

Answer (score 1):

I found my issue was that I was trying to use the app engine plugin for eclipse 4.3. I just downloaded the new eclipse and it works now. Sorry, thats the best I have..

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and Nicky Jaidev's post helped me.

I had to update the Java Sdk to 1.7.

But also you have to update the eclipse.ini:

-vm
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_45/bin/javaw.exe

If you don't change this, it will keep failing.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the AppEngine SDK version is intended for other version of Eclipse.

For Eclipse 4.2 (Juno), use this link: https://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.2

Follow the installation guide here if you unsure about how to install plugins through Eclipse directly: https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/install-eclipse-4.2

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with app engine plugin for Eclipse 4.2 (well, it was the Android Developer Tools version), on Mac 
OS 10.8.4.

After I saw this warning about Java 6 not being supported, https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/installing, I upgraded to the latest version of Java 7 and it worked.