# Creating a Web Application Project following Google App Engine tutorial

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-app-engine, eclipse-plugin

following [this](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/creating) tutorial. I have run into this error:

[image]

when I navigate to the specified folder, I find the freshly installed files just as I expect them:

[image]

I using the Eclipse plugin.

And now I have no idea of what to try next.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iRuth is right just as it suggests [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19167171/appengine-sdk-1-8-5-and-eclipse-juno-not-working)

reinstalling the Java SDK will fix it.

Answer (score 0):

The instruction in the page link you gave said you should:

> Uncheck "Use Google Web Toolkit," and ensure "Use Google App Engine" is checked.

From the snapshot you provided, I can see that you didn't uncheck Google Web Toolkit. Try unchecking it and see if it solves the problem.

**UPDATE:**

You could also try updating your Java SDK as this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19167171/appengine-sdk-1-8-5-and-eclipse-juno-not-working) suggests.

Comment: lets continue this discussion in chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41335/never-know-what-to-call-these